# C# File Upload works locally; not on Azure

Tags: c#, file, azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I have a C# web application which uploads an image file to Azure Blob Storage. I am passing the local path of image file from a textbox (no File Upload Controller). This application works locally as expected. But when I publish it on Azure, it throws exception.

> Could not find file (filename)

What changes should be made to run it on Azure?

**Code :**

```
CloudBlobContainer container = Program.BlobUtilities.GetBlobClient.GetContainerReference(Container);// container 
            container.CreateIfNotExists();
            container.SetPermissions(new BlobContainerPermissions
            {
                PublicAccess = BlobContainerPublicAccessType.Blob
            });
            CloudBlobDirectory directory = container.GetDirectoryReference(foldername);
            // Get reference to blob (binary content)
            CloudBlockBlob blockBlob_image = directory.GetBlockBlobReference(imageid);
                 using (var filestream = System.IO.File.OpenRead(image_path))
                {
                    blockBlob_image.UploadFromStream(filestream);
                }
```

Comment: You're trying to 'upload' a file by pointing to the file _on your computer_. So when you run the website _on your computer_, it'll work. If you run the website _somewhere else_, it will not be able to find that file. This is not uploading, it's copying the file. Implement proper uploading to a controller.

Comment: I am using web forms. not mvc. Also, even using FileUpload Control, it gives same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, Found the solution. Instead of passing file path to a textbox, I used FileUpload Controller. In the code-behind,

```
Stream image_path = FileUpload1.FileContent;
```

Actually, earlier too I had tried using FileUpload controller, but `Server.MapPath(FileUpload1.Filename)` and `Path.GetFullPath(FileUpload1.FileName)` were not giving the correct path.

Also,

```
           using (var filestream = image_path)
           {
        blockBlob_image.UploadFromStream(image_path);
           }
```

is replaced by

```
blockBlob_image.UploadFromStream(image_path);
```

Answer (score 1):

> Could not find file (filename)

The exception is caused by `System.IO.File.OpenRead(filePath)`, as you Web Application is published to Azure. If you want use System.IO.File.OpenRead(filePath), you need to make sure that the filepath could be found in the [WebApp](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Azure-Web-App-sandbox).

> What changes should be made to run it on Azure?

If you want to use the code on the Azure, you need to make sure that the file could be found in the Azue Website. You need to copy the file to Azure. If you want to upload file to the Azure blob, it is not recommanded. Since that you need to copy the file to Azure WebApp first.

Also As you mentioned that you could use FileUpload Controller to do that.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably using the path to your computer which will be different on azure. You can try change the path to something like this:

```
string path = HostingEnvironment.ApplicationPhysicalPath + @"\YourProjectName\PathToFile"
```

Comment: I want path like "C:\Users\User\Desktop\1.jpg".
'Using Server.MapPath(FileUpload1.FileName)' or 'Path.GetFullPath(..)' gives different values.

Comment: Can you try to edit your post with the code that's failing?

Comment: Otherwise it's gonna be hard to identify your problem